# Polymer application organisation - elements vs pure JS

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

So I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Polymer, and while there are a lot of basic samples around, they don't tend to go too deep in to how a larger app might be structured.

Watching the Polymer 1.0 session from I/O, it was very heavily implied that elements were the way to go for everything, showing a bunch of purely declarative demos, with the 'theres an element for that' mantra.

Looking at the IO Web App/IOWA source they released though, they seem to have this global IOWA JS object doing a lot of their heavy lifting; for example instead of things like core-ajax/iron-ajax, they've got IOWA.Request doing regular XHRs.

I realise IOWA is written on 0.5, which I hadn't really looked too seriously at, but I can't help but feel a little lost around how to structure apps going forward with 1.0.

I guess I'm just not really sold on using elements for everything; IOWA only goes to reinforce this. But is that actually the way I should be looking at it (element based)?

Comment: look over a real app .... https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome-material    its 0.5 but still worth a look if you want to take time to relate it to a n implementation.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, each UI item is a component, perhaps a search bar, a map, a component that selects tags. In addition, there's ajax elements, which specify URLs etc, and JS methods on such are called in on-click methods, for example. And, if you look at the firebase element, you can use such to connect to firebase to bind such data to your app.

Have a look at the elements catalogue for more examples: https://elements.polymer-project.org/

It's basically leveraging elements, which live in files and directories in your app when you created your own, and connecting such together using javascript: a tags component using an ajax element to fetch its data, an as example.

You could, for example, use pure js for ajax or firebase calls, but declaratively specifying the elements, with URLs and other such details, and then using js to reference and manipulate such in an encapsulated element is, arguably, a better approach: you are separating out what is declarative (URL, type of method, etc) and what is procedural (calling the ajax method etc).

That is, using web components, and polymer, is to accept a lot of web development is nicer if you can make the declarative parts of web development declarative, using connected custom elements. And the best way to achieve that is to use HTML elements, with your javascript living in each element. It's not JS vs Elements, but more JS + encapsulated, reusable elements.